# Android setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled not working with Samsung

Tags: android, scrollview, samsung-mobile, fading, samsung-touchwiz

I have several samsung devices (GT-I9192/4.2.2, GT-I9295/4.2.2 etc) for testing purposes and all of it wont show fading edges for HorisontalScrollView. All other smatrphones like HTC, Motorola, Meizu and so on (mostly aos 4.x and several are 2.3.5) shows fading edges well.
 Since in api14 new property was added `android:requiresFadingEdge` and it has NO code alternative (at least I didn't found it) Im using the following layout (this scroll used for tabs scrolling):

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabs_horisontal_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="32dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layerType="software" //was thinking it might help but it doesn't
    android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Like I'd said everything works fine on any smartphone but not on samsung ones. Actually samsung devices does draw the fadingEdge and it looks the same on all samsung devices BUT it looks like its 2-3px of width max. So I'd noticed that it draws it but not 32dp and it ignores everything about FadingEdge settings. Probably the only turning off is working well.
 So what could be the issue?

Comment: Have you resolved this somehow? It doesn't work on Samsung devices as you mentioned.

Comment: I didn't found any solution so it looks like you have to draw edges manually (like in PhotoShop) and include it programmatically as images at edges.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `android:overScrollMode` attribute.

Just add

```
android:overScrollMode="always"
```

to your `HorizontalScrollView`.

> android:overScrollMode can have three values: "always", "never", "ifContentScrolls".

Comment: I can't check it since I don't have those Samsung devices anymore. However I assume that this wont help either. Like I mentioned in my question Samsung DOES display fadingEdge but its too thin so its mostly unnoticeable. So the problem is mostly about edge configuring (and seems like on Samsung devices its not configurable).